# mbunit v2 vs v3 xml report files

Tags: c#, mbunit, gallio

Our test source tree currently contains c# projects that either contain mbunit v2 tests or v3 tests (the newest projects). Our old v2 test projects were exes that used the "autorunner" to generate XML reports. Since the new projects are using Gallio which does not have the autorunner, we use gallio.echo.exe to generate the appropriate xml file for a given test assembly.

Now the problem: We have an internal tool developed some time ago that looks at the xml report files to determine if certain customer requirements are being met. This was written for mbunit v2. It seems the xml files produced by echo are different.

So...Is there any way to get echo to produce xml reports that look like v2 reports? We need to avoid rewriting our internal tool (for now)...is there anyway we can get echo to produce xml files that look like they used to for v2?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, Gallio does not support emitting MbUnit v2 compatible tesdt report XML.  It is possible to do this by writing a custom report XSL template but it would be a lot of work.

Gallio's test model is much more general and more powerful than MbUnit v2's and it would be very difficult to shoehorn the results into the older format.

You will probably find it easier to rewrite your tool.  Alternately if your tool does something that may be of general use to others then you might try sending it to me (via the gallio-dev mailing list) and I could see about incorporating some of its features directly into Gallio or into a new report format.

Comment: Incidentally, Gallio can run your old v2 tests too.  You don't even need to change how they are compiled.  Just pass in the .exe's to Gallio.Echo.